# Environment variable value not set, but why?

Tags: batch-file, scope, automated-tests

Why is batch variable TESTTYPE not passed through to the calling batch file (Windows 7 machine)?

I trigger a test system via SVN commit message. Given e.g. this SVN message:

> This should trigger my test system for a long test.
>
> testing RunTest#longtest

Problem: The command `set` at the end of the inner batch file properly outputs `longtest` but the outer batch file outputs `smoketest` unexpectedly.

---

This is the calling batch file `test.bat`:

```
call %~dp0gettype.bat trunk 12345
echo %TESTTYPE%
```

---

This is the called batch file `gettype.bat` doing the work:

```
set TESTTYPE=smoketest

::find all lines in the string which contain the keyword "RunTest#"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=svn log -r %2 -v | findstr /r "RunTest#""

::for all words in that found line call the subroutine "handleElement"
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('!cmd!') do (
    if "%%a" NEQ "" for %%b in (%%a) do call:handleElement %%b
)
goto ende

::split on hashtag char and handle the keyword after the hashtag (and find the type)
:handleElement
set TMPSTR=%1
set TAGNAME=%TMPSTR:~0,8%
if "%TAGNAME%"=="RunTest#" call:getSpecialType %TMPSTR:~8%
goto:eof

:getSpecialType
set TESTTYPE=%1
goto:eof

:ende
set
```

Comment: When the called batch file ends, the `setlocal` is reverted and all the changes to the environment variables are discarded. As your code is not using delayed expansion, remove the `setlocal` command.

Comment: Now I've also added the batch code which generates the string to be parsed. Now it's more clear why I have to use setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Comment: No, the code you have posted does not **require** delayed expansion. Change `!cmd!` to `%cmd%` and use `set "cmd=svn log -r %2 -v ^| findstr /r "RunTest#""`

Comment: @MCND: this works pretty well, why don't you write it as answer? :-)

Comment: Argh, never use an environment variable called TMP! It took me a while to find out why following batch calls failed with "failed to create temporary file name" :-] I changed it to TMPSTR now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
call %~dp0gettype.bat
echo %TESTTYPE%
```

to

```
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`call %~dp0gettype.bat`) do set "TESTTYPE=%%i"
echo %TESTTYPE%
```

and in `gettype.bat`

change

```
:ende
set
```

to

```
:ende
echo %TESTTYPE%
```

Comment: yeah, works well :-) Am I right, it takes over the echo output of gettype.bat?

Comment: @falkb Yes. `for` can grab the output of the command/s within parentheses, so as `gettype.bat` echoes a value, it may be captured this way.

Comment: Your answer has the advantage that, when processing just the output of echo, I don't need to pollute the outer environment with variables I actually just need to set in the inner batch file, right?

Comment: almost yes. The first comment from MC ND tells you that child processes cannot change the parent enviroment. This avoid filling parent environment, but to pass back any value we need either use the for technique or use a temp file. Also, you may use setlocal endlocal in your batch subroutines, to isolate variable scope.

Comment: Actually, both of you should get the honour but MC ND has not provided it as answer. So here we go with accepting this as answer. Thanks!